# simple script to remove files in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, path

I made a simple script in linux bash just like bellow:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/tmp_with_zip_files
FILETYPE=zip
i=1

for filename in $PATH/*.$FILETYPE;
do
        echo "rm $filename";

        if [ -f $filename ];
                then rm $filename;
        fi

        i=$((i+1))
done

echo "$i files removed"
```

But, when i run script i have error,  because script doesnt work correctly. It's mean from console i have a message:

```
zip_delete.sh: line 11: rm: command not found
```

Why linux bash script not recognize linux command rm?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3):

Lol I think it's because you're overwriting the default `$PATH` variable (which is the variable that tells bash where to look for executables). During execution, it can't find the `rm` program in `PATH` because it's pointing to only `/tmp_with_zip_files`

Use a different variable name for your purposes like `chicken_nuggets`.

WARNING DON'T DO THE FOLLOWING LMAO `PATH=$PATH:/tmp_with_zip_files` you could delete a bunch of things from `PATH` and that would suck really bad

Comment: Gotcha. I saw your comment on the other answer and changed it to a much more appropriate variable name. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `PATH` variable holds the path to OS commands (like `rm`), don't use that as a variable, name it something else, like `path_to_files`.

Comment: Like `path`, rather. The POSIX standard reserves all-caps variables for OS use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*

Comment: @Charles Duffy - Corrected